# Is it possible to put a Ribbon or RibbonTab in seperate xaml file?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, ribbon

Repo: https://github.com/babakin34/ribbontest1/

I have a **Main.xaml** and a **MyRibbon.xaml**.

MyRibbon.xaml

```
<ribbon:Ribbon xmlns:ribbon="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="">
        <ribbon:RibbonMenuButton Label="Upload"/>
    </ribbon:RibbonTab>
</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

MyRibbon.xaml.cs

```
public class MyRibbon : Ribbon {}
```

Main.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <MyRibbon/>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that an empty Ribbon is shown in Grid. (The upload menu is misisng)

Here is the whole project snapshot:

[image]

Comment: Is there anything shown if you have `<Grid>
    <Ribbon/>
</Grid>`?

Comment: yes, if I add the content of MyRibbon.xaml directly inside Main.xaml, I get the expected result.

Comment: I'm not familiar with wpf, but perhaps make `MyRibbon` class public?

Comment: MyRibbon class  is public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic connection between your `MyRibbon` class and the `MyRibbon.xaml` file.

If you want to create custom control you should define a *template* for it:

```
public class MyRibbon : Ribbon {}
```

---

```
<Grid xmlns:ribbon="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="local:MyRibbon">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyRibbon">
                        <ribbon:Ribbon>
                            <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="">
                                <ribbon:RibbonMenuButton Label="Upload"/>
                            </ribbon:RibbonTab>
                        </ribbon:Ribbon>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <local:MyRibbon/>
</Grid>
```

The other option would be to simply create a `UserControl` called MyRibbon and put your XAML markup in the MyRibbon.xaml file. You can then use the `UserControl` like this:

```
<local:MyRibbon />
```

1. Create a new UserControl (Project->Add New Item->User Control (WPF) and name it "MyRibbon".
2. Replace the contents of the MyRibbon.xaml file with the following:

   ```
   <Ribbon x:Class="WpfApplication3.MyRibbon"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
       <RibbonTab Header="">
           <RibbonMenuButton Label="Upload"/>
       </RibbonTab>
   </Ribbon>
   ```
3. Change the base class in MyRibbon.xaml.cs:

   ```
   public partial class MyRibbon : System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.Ribbon
   {
       public MyRibbon()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add the control to your Main.xaml:

   ```
   <local:MyRibbon />
   ```

[image]

Comment: I am using the second method and getitng an empty Ribbon without the Upload menu.

Comment: You are not using the second approach if you have one file called MyRibbon.xaml and another one called MyRibbon.cs. Please read my answeer again and try to create a UserControl.

Comment: I am doing exactly what you are proposing but the Upload menu is misisng. Please check my question again,  I added a screenshot of the whole project.

Comment: You are overriding the contents of  MyRibbon when you set its Content to the "Download" RibbonTab.

Comment: It doesn't matter. When I remove the download menu and use <local:MyRibbon Grid.Row="0" /> I still don't see any Upload menu.

Comment: I upload an Image of what I see using my sample code. Make sure that height of your grid row isn't to small. And please provide a full repo if you need any further help.

Comment: By the way I am using Visual Studio 2015 Prof.

Comment: I had the "x:Class" attribute wrong and InitializeComponent() method was missing. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. 
MyRibbon.xaml:

```
<ribbon:Ribbon  x:Class="XFWPF.WPF.MyRibbon"
                xmlns:ribbon="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ribbon:RibbonTab Header="">
        <ribbon:RibbonMenuButton Label="Upload"/>
    </ribbon:RibbonTab>
</ribbon:Ribbon>
```

Main.xaml: Kindly note that, uc corresponds to the namespace of MyRibbon(XFWPF.WPF).

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <uc:MyRibbon/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: How does your MyRibbon.cs look like ?

Comment: using System.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;
namespace XFWPF.WPF.View{
    public partial class MyRibbon : Ribbon    {
        public MyRibbon()  {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

Comment: For my info, are you not getting compile error for <MyRibbon/>? To my understanding, you need to provide the xmlns tag to it.

Comment: Are you sure, that you can see the "Upload" menu ?

Comment: I get an empty Ribbon.

Comment: I have the namespace in code, i removed it when copy pasting here.

Comment: Yes, I was able to see the upload menu. I posted here after testing.